# Python running many scripts from one

Tags: python, module

I have many python scripts I would like to run in succession (or concurrently).

For example:
program1.py -

program2.py -

program 1 and 2 execute equivalent commands but for different sets of input.

program3.py combines output from program 1 and 2 and produces additional output. I have many of these. Eventually they produce one final output from everything. It is necessary to keep them organized this way.

Is there a best way to go about this?

I have tried importing as a module but seems there is probably a much better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you only need to use subprocess:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html